# What does includeKey do ?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm really confused about the PFQuery's includeKey: method.
Say I have an instance of class Foo containing a String property name 'state' and a pointer to another class instance (say a Bar instance) as 'bar'.

When I query instances of Foo I want the info on the Bar instance they are related too:

```
let query = PFQuery("Foo")
    .whereKey("state", equalTo: "Active")
    .includeKey("bar")
```

Does this fetch the Bar instance properties ? Such that I can do:

```
let foo = query.getFirstObject() as! Foo
// access Bar property
foo.bar.baz = "Yep"
```

What if the Foo bar property is not a pointer but an object ?

Thanks for your help

B.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "includeKey" will include 'bar' as a PFObject in your query results.

In Swift you should cast "bar" as a PFObject in order to access the properties.

```
if let bar = foo["bar"] as? PFObject {
    println(bar["baz"])
}
```

Comment: You can also do multi-level includes, so lets say the `bar` object has a pointer to a `foobar` object in the field `foo`, you could do `[query includeKey:@"bar.foo"]` to automatically fetch this object as well